# Функциональное программирование в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой решения задачи на одном из курсов. При составлении данного кода в этой строке

```
 lambda z: tuple(z)
```

среда выдаёт ошибку

> Lambda may not be necessary (unnecessary-lambda)

Полный код представлен ниже. Не могу понять, как можно оптимизировать лямбду.

```
import itertools
import functools
print(*(tuple([[[0]]]) + tuple(
    *map(lambda data: filter(lambda x: tuple(x[0]) == x[1],
        map(lambda variant: (
            filter(lambda bet: ((variant.index(bet[0]) >= variant.index(bet[1])) ^
                                (variant.index(bet[2]) >= variant.index(bet[3]))),
                   data[1]), data[1], variant + data[2]), data[0])),
         map(lambda x: (itertools.permutations(
             set(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, x[1]))), x[1],
                        tuple(set(range(1, x[0] + 1)) - set(functools.reduce(
            lambda x, y: x + y, x[1])))),
             map(lambda dataEntered: (next(dataEntered),
                                      tuple(set(map(
                                          lambda z: tuple(z),
                                              map(lambda x: map(int, input().split()),
                         range(next(dataEntered))))))), [map(int, input().split())])
             ))
))[-1][-1])
```

Входные данные
Ввод

3 2

2 1 2 3

1 2 3 2

Вывод

3 2 1

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение. В данном случае эту лямбду можно заменить просто на `tuple`

Comment: Может не надо это было выкладывать под меткой питон. На неокрепшие функционально умы питонистов это воздействует... э...

Comment: insolor, при изменении на tuple действительно программа проходит и работает, правда, падает.
Victor VosMottor - Дети должны увидеть ужасы взрослого мира

Comment: Ужасы какие )) Особенно пачка скобок впечатлила `dataEntered)))))))`

Comment: @Vadim, не боитесь так писать? На работу же не возьмут (где после вас найти такого же умника, который разберется с таким кодом **и сколько он будет стоить?**)

Comment: https://twitter.com/kyrah/status/786199499714629632

Comment: Мне нравится. Прямо [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html). В функциональном программировании есть возможность написать любую программу не определяя ни одной функции. Кажется, это подобный пример. Его не сложно разобрать на отдельные функции. И в реальности, конечно, никто так не пишет.

Comment: Вызовы `functools.reduce` можно заменить на `sum`.

Comment: [η-преобразование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%CE%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: extrn - Хороший совет, спасибо, надеюсь, ещё поможет
Stanislav Volodarskiy - Да, верное замечание, но исправлять не стал
andreymal и @CrazyElf - классика)
avp - мы все в жизни с чем то столкнёмся, о чём потому будет стыдно рассказывать)

Вопрос решён, спасибо за помощь ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение `lambda z: tuple(z)` полностью взаимозаменяемо с `tuple`. Это верно для любой функции `f` вместо `tuple`:

`lambda x: f(x)` <=> `f`

`lambda *args: f(*args)` <=> `f`

`lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)` <=> `f`

Comment: Чтож, на удивление, сразу не сработало, когда я заменял и выдавало ошибку (не могу объяснить её причину), но после перезагрузки компьютера ваш совет и совет @insolor помог, спасибо